Excel: auto populate weekly dates in a spread sheet
I have a spread sheet that looks like the below picture.  The way i create this is:

i calculate the weekly thursday from the year in cell B4
i then set the fromula in B5 to "=B4+7".
i drag that down to fill the first month of jan
then i select from A4 to B8 and drag that down to fill the sheet for the rest of the months
and finally i insert to Quarter rows.

THe problem is when a new year starts, this may not work, especially if a month has 5 weeks in a year.   Is there a way to do this in a way such that if i change the year, the sheet auto populates those rows correctly based on what im looking for as decribed above?
Here is the what image and what i have built using the steps descibed above.

EDIT: prob not important, but the formuala should reference B1 for the date.  in current spreadsheet im working i have it the O3 cell also.

Try: =SEQUENCE(WEEKNUM(DATE(B1,12,31))-1,,WORKDAY.INTL(DATE(B1,1,1)-1,1,"1110111"),7)

As you correctly noticed, week count for every month may vary depending on year. Solving your task with a formula might be possible but is very impractical, especially if you need subtotals for every month and quarter. You might look into utilizing a pivot table instead.

@ttaaoossuuuu do you have an example of such i can read (if you can not provide one?)


VBA is an option to create the date table

Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim arrData, rngData As Range, rngTotal As Range
    Dim arrRes(1 To 72, 1 To 2), iR As Long, iMth As Long, sMth As String
    Dim LastRow As Long, iDate As Date, iWK As Long
    Dim oSht As Worksheet
    Const START_ROW = 4
    Set oSht = Sheets("Sheet1")  ' modify as needed
    ' validate YEAR on cell B1
    If Len(oSht.Range("B1")) = 0 Or (Not IsNumeric(oSht.Range("B1"))) Then
        MsgBox "Please input Year in cell B1"
        oSht.Range("B1").Select
        Exit Sub
    End If
    LastRow = oSht.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    ' Clean the table
    If LastRow >= START_ROW Then oSht.Range(START_ROW & ":" & LastRow).Clear
    ' get the first Thursday
    iDate = VBA.DateSerial(oSht.Range("B1"), 1, 1)
    iWK = 4 - VBA.Weekday(iDate, vbMonday)
    If iWK < 0 Then iWK = iWK + 7
    iDate = iDate + iWK
    ' loop through each Thursday
    Do
        iR = iR + 1
        If VBA.Month(iDate) > iMth Then
            If iMth > 0 Then
                ' populate Mth total and Qtr total
                arrRes(iR, 2) = sMth & " Total"
                Set rngTotal = MergeRng(rngTotal, oSht.Cells(START_ROW + iR - 1, 2))
                iR = iR + 1
                If iMth Mod 3 = 0 Then
                    arrRes(iR, 2) = "Q" & iMth \ 3 & " Total"
                    Set rngTotal = MergeRng(rngTotal, oSht.Cells(START_ROW + iR - 1, 2))
                    iR = iR + 1
                End If
            End If
            ' populate the date
            iMth = VBA.Month(iDate)
            sMth = Format(VBA.DateSerial(2000, iMth, 1), "MMM")
            arrRes(iR, 1) = sMth
        End If
        arrRes(iR, 2) = iDate
        iDate = iDate + 7
    Loop Until iDate > VBA.DateSerial(Range("B1"), 12, 31)
    ' last total
    iR = iR + 1
    arrRes(iR, 2) = sMth & " Total"
    arrRes(iR + 1, 2) = "Q" & iMth \ 3 & " Total"
    ' write output to sheet
    Set rngTotal = MergeRng(rngTotal, oSht.Cells(START_ROW + iR - 1, 2).Resize(2))
    oSht.Cells(START_ROW, 1).Resize(iR + 1, 2).Value = arrRes
    ' apply date formatting
    oSht.Range("B" & START_ROW, oSht.Range("B" & START_ROW).End(xlDown)).NumberFormatLocal = "m/d/yyyy"
    ' apply total formatting, modify as needed
    If Not rngTotal Is Nothing Then
        With rngTotal
            .Interior.Color = RGB(192, 230, 245)
            .Font.Bold = True
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignRight
            .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        End With
    End If
End Sub

' UDF to merge two ranges
Function MergeRng(RngAll As Range, RngSub As Range) As Range
    If RngAll Is Nothing Then
        Set RngAll = RngSub
    Else
        Set RngAll = Application.Union(RngAll, RngSub)
    End If
    Set MergeRng = RngAll
End Function


